# Transcation timeout issue, because of DB is getting locked

Tags: java, atomikos

We have two database one is master and other is slave. we are placing 2 locks in both the db and to make them in sync we are placing one exclusive lock on top of that.

Now  the problem is, timer has expired while updating the row in the master DB table. The master table lock is dead due to this issue and still we have one lock in slave table and exclusive lock in both the tables.  Because of this we are not able to update the row in table. 
We don't have any clue why lock in master db is dead and still the global lock is not releasing that row.

I have tried `setReapTimeout()` method. It was also not working. can someone help...

Atomikos Error:

```
javax.transaction.xa.XAException: java.sql.SQLException: System or internal error
    at com.informix.jdbcx.IfxXAResource.end(IfxXAResource.java:125)
    at com.atomikos.datasource.xa.XAResourceTransaction.suspend(XAResourceTransaction.java:611)
    at com.atomikos.datasource.xa.XAResourceTransaction.rollback(XAResourceTransaction.java:864)
    at com.atomikos.icatch.imp.RollbackMessage.send(RollbackMessage.java:90)
    at com.atomikos.icatch.imp.PropagationMessage.submit(PropagationMessage.java:86)
    at com.atomikos.icatch.imp.Propagator$PropagatorThread.run(Propagator.java:62)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```